# Integration tests pass locally but fail on Azure Devops with 400 Bad Request - Invalid Hostname C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, testing, azure-devops, integration-testing

In tests :

```
var query = "api/objectives?Year=2022&menteeId=eb32dd9d-ee98-400d-8567-811728840487";
_factory = new CustomWebApplicationFactory<Program>(provider, AppendLogEntry);
_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
_client = _factory.CreateClient();
_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Host", "localhost");
 //Act
var response = await _client.GetAsync(query);
var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
// Assert
response.StatusCode.ShouldBe(HttpStatusCode.OK, content);
```

**Error:**

```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></ HEAD >
**<BODY><h2>Bad Request - Invalid Hostname</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid.</p>**
</BODY></HTML>
```

---

I tried to set  _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Host", "localhost"); but still not working...

Comment: `localhost` is not going to work in an Azure service. Assuming Azure App Service, you will have a host name of 'something'.azurewebsites.net

Comment: In other posts I saw that _client.DefaultRequestHeaders is not set at all and it works fine, but not for me.

Comment: I can't imagine a case where you have to set the Host header manually (assuming you provide the host as part of the URL). That said: What is the exact error message if your remove the host header? And: As @Crowcoder wrote, you need to provide the correct url including the correct host. "localhost" is wrong.

Comment: Without "_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Host", "localhost");" tests pass locally in VS Code but the pipeline in Azure (CI) fails with the same error Bad Request invalid hostname.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: I tried to create a dockerfile and to run the test there. Everthing was ok. It seems that it was a problem from Azure Devops.